# ckEditor and jQuery what am I missing?

Tags: jquery, html, ckeditor

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="adapters/jquery.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myeditor').ckeditor();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myeditor">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing is displayed...

Have I missed something ? All the javascript/css files are in the right places..

Any ideas ??

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: No errors, jquery1.4.2 is included. Just nothing is displayed.

jGrowl and heaps of other plugins seem to work ok.

But I cant seem to get the ckeditor (with its jquery adapter) to display.

Comment: http://download.cksource.com/CKEditor/CKEditor/CKEditor%203.3.2/ckeditor_3.3.2.zip 
Is the version of ckeditor being used, the adapters/jquery.js is inside the zip file.

And the jquery 1.4.2min is the default version from the jquery website.

The rest of the html is included in the question.. So nothing too fancy..

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

ckEditor requires the following files:

1) ckeditor.js
2) adapters/jquery.js
3) contents.css
4) cojnfig.js

I was missing (3) and (4)

Oh.. And if you want skins/images/themes.. You need the subdirectories also.